# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'persist'

Tags: function, pyspark, persist

When I try to persist `Dataframe` in pyspark, I meet the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'persist'` error. pseudo code is as follows:

```
ss = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sqlDF = ss.sql(query) // query contains udf
sqlDF.persist()
```

The result of `ss.sql(query).show(10)` is like follows

```
      dt|  t|                   u| ra| tm|tra|  alg| fa|
+----------+---+--------------------+---+---+---+-----+---+
|2019-04-22|  1|0e4466fb752e0ff6a...|  2|   |   |h5_rl|   |
|2019-04-22|  1|05ce59ff55b70a805...|  4|   |   | null|   |
|2019-04-22|  1|07bc6ebd8f9d0082d...|  2|   |   |h5_rl|   |
```

Is the error caused by that some of the cell value are of nonetype? If so, how to solve it?

Comment: You can try sqlDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try print out the schema of the `sqlDF` with `sqlDF.printSchema()`and find that some column is of `NoneType` so that spark doesn't know how to serialize them. It may be caused by all values of some column is null, then spark infer the schema of that column as `NoneType`. You can manually cast the column to a desired type in the query.